# What are the pros and cons, if any, of purchasing Treasury securities at a reopened auction (vs. a new, non-reopened auction)?

Tags: united-states, bonds, treasury, securities, auction

I read on [treasurydirect.gov](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/when-auctions-happen/schedule-auction-reopenings/):

> When we hold a reopening auction, we are selling additional amounts of a previously issued security.

This is reflected in the [Tentative-Auction-Schedule.pdf](https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/221/Tentative-Auction-Schedule.pdf).

What are the pros and cons, if any, of purchasing Treasury securities at a reopened auction (vs. a new, non-reopened Treasury auction)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not really any pros or cons - you'll still pay a price equivalent to the market yield of securities with the same time to maturity, otherwise there would be arbitrage opportunities. You will pay any interest that has accrued from the issue date up to the point of purchase, but that will be accounted for in the price as well. Meaning that the listed price may be slightly lower than a newly issued bond would have, but the additional accrued interest will cancel that out.

The timing of coupons will be slightly different since you'll get the first coupon sooner than the 6 months you'd wait until the first coupon for a new bond.

It is possible that a reopening could have a significantly different *coupon rate* than a newly issued bond would have if interest rates have changed significantly, which will have secondary effects like sensitivity to interest rates (duration), since bonds with higher coupons have less sensitivity to interest ate changes. But those differences could go either way.

Bottom line - a reopening does not mean that you get bonds that are cheaper or more expensive that original bonds - you're really paying for the yield which will be equivalent regardless of when the bond was issued.